# Any way to flag bad lines in pandas when reading an excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

`pandas.read_csv` has `(warn, error)` bad lines methods. I can't see any for `pandas.read_excel`. Is there a reason? For example, if I wanted to read an excel file where a column is supposed to be a `datetime` and the `pandas.read_execl` function encounters an `int` or `str` in one/few of the rows. Do i need to handle this myself?

Comment: did my solution help you? If so, then kindly accept as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no I do not believe there is a way to do automatically do this with a parameter you pass to `read_excel()`. This is how to solve your problem though:

Let's say that when you read in your dataframe it looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Desktop/Book1.xlsx')
df
                   Date
0   2020-09-13 00:00:00
1   2
2   abc
3   2020-09-14 00:00:00
```

You can you pass `errors='coerce'` to `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df

          Date
0   2020-09-13
1   NaT
2   NaT
3   2020-09-14
```

Finally, you can drop those rows with:

```
df = df[df['Date'].notnull()]
df

          Date
0   2020-09-13
3   2020-09-14
```

Comment: And finally reset index would be more perfect. - `df = df[df['Date'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thanks. I will accept the answer, although it is not exactly what I was hoping for. The issue is that I have to explicitly write this for every column (which can be nicely organized as converters, but still..)